# Can we please hold the hats?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

I really like the hats game. But I would love to keep the hats longer then only one winter. I want to leave them in my wardrobe during summer. Last year, I collected some cool hats, and I apparently lost them during summer.

Maybe we could make a system that allows hats to last for about 2 or 3 years, so we don't have to start over each winter. Or even specify per type of hat a number of years they last? Very very rare hats could last for ever.

I asked this, simply because I love hats! :D

Comment: Also, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159171/178816 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211972/permanent-hat-like-thing/211980#211980

Comment: I think one of the beautiful part of hats is being _temporary_. It is all for christmas fun. I don't want to keep them for all year. Of course, this is just my opinion..

Comment: This should be posted as an answer on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213574/what-should-we-consider-for-next-years-winter-bash, but I don't think this is a dupe of that.

Answer (score 12):

I think the point of hats is to be temporary, a fun thing just for the holiday season, not to be worn at any other times. They would lose meaning if we could keep getting more hats throughout the year, they would just be wearable badges.

However, what would be nice is an archive of hats that you got from previous years, but you wouldn't be able to wear them.

Comment: I don't want to wear them all time through the year. I just want to keep my special hats for the year after this one. Easy hats should be removed every year, I think. But I would love to keep the cool ones so I can wear them next year.

Comment: But "easy hats" is very subjective, and there's no 'hat levels' like there are with badges

Comment: That is why the question has the *feature-request* tag. :) What not is can come, right? :)

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux if you want to keep them but not wear them, why not take screen caps before they get packed up?  Last year they made a point of warning us as the deadline approached, and there was even a suggestion to take screen caps if you wanted.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think the point, which would make some sense to me, was: you should be able to keep your hats from this year... and then be able to wear them again next year when hats come back out. Or at least the interesting ones.

Comment: It would be a cool feature to select one hat you can keep to next year! This would mean no one has to define what "easy hats" are. Everyone can keep the one hat he likes the most!